# No audio through HDMI with Gigabyte Brix

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

Newbie to Ubuntu (13.10 x64 desktop) and have been trying to get audio to work on a Gibabyte Brix (GB-BXi3-4010) through HDMI but no go.  If I plug into the standard headphone jack audio works no problem.  By default Ubuntu views HDMI as a possible audio output in the sound settings but will not output.  Installed ALSA mixer and it will show Intel Haswell as a tab but no output options.  Missing driver?

```
aplay -l output:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC269VC Digital [ALC269VC Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I just got a Brix GB-BXi3H-4010 myself, installed Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit on it, and I also have sound issues. I can get sound output after selecting HDMI 5.1 as output device, but the sound stutters and the channels are all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I have Kubuntu 15.04. Also did not have audio, just went to System Settings/Multimedia. I changed the preference for audio playback to HDMI for all categories. Sound works now without problem.